# Native crash of my app on Google play console Pre-launch report details

Tags: android, flutter, testing, store

I have this crash in my Pre-launch report details at Google play.
What's the problem here? and how can I solve it?

```
Build fingerprint: 'generic/gce_x86_phone/gce_x86:9/PGR1.190916.001/5877764:userdebug/test-keys'

Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 7566, tid: 8624, name: 1.ui  >>> com.#########.########### <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/lib/ui/semantics/semantics_update_builder.cc(85)] Check failed: transform.data() && SkScalarsAreFinite(*transform.data(), 9). Semantics update transform was not set or not finite.
'
    eax 00000000  ebx 00001d8e  ecx 000021b0  edx 00000006
    edi c4b4d9c8  esi 00000000
    ebp c4b4ce98  esp c4b4cddc  eip eb1debe9
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000be9  [vdso:eb1de000] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
    #01 pc 000789ec  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+28)
    #02 pc 00092447  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::RunHostSpecificSyscallImpl(int, int, int, int, int, int, int)+423)
    #03 pc 0008cb93  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::RunKernelSyscall(int, int, int, int, int, int, int)+243)
    #04 pc 00078c42  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::SVC(ndk_translation::ProcessState*, ndk_translation::SVC_Args const&)+50)
    #05 pc 00099b0c  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::InsnInterpreter::CallInterp(unsigned int, void const*, void const*)+44)
    #06 pc 000b30ec  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::SemanticsDecoder::SVC(ndk_translation::SVC_Args const&)+108)
    #07 pc 000ed7cb  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::ArmDecoder::TranslateThumbInsn(unsigned short const*)+8891)
    #08 pc 0009b390  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::(anonymous namespace)::DecodeInsn(unsigned int, ndk_translation::(anonymous namespace)::ArmInterpreter*, ndk_translation::ProcessState*, ndk_translation::ArmDecoder*)+112)
    #09 pc 0009b5b7  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::InterpretTrace(ndk_translation::ProcessState*)+327)
    #10 pc 00079f0d  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation_HandleNotTranslated+285)
    #11 pc 0018db57  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so
```

It occurs in one device (emulator):
[image]

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you find any solution ? also are you using flutter local notifications?

Comment: for the first question, I think it's a bug in flutter, check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37396 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105903.  for the second question, no I don't.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a bug from flutter side, for more details see:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37396 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105903

currently I am going to publish the update of my app with the latest stable version (setting the minSdkVersion to 29 as suggested in the links), I tried it with internal testing and it passed without any crash! it's a temporary solution waiting to fix this flutter bug.